# Place a scrim above an ImageView shown using Picasso

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, picasso

I'm showing an image using Picasso into an ImageView in a toolbar and I gotta make readable the Toolbar title even if it's a B&W pic so I want to add a scrim that should add a shadow starting from the bottom of the image, just like this.

[image: Left without scrim, right with scrim]

I've tried adding it to the xml and it's covered by the image shown with Picasso, also tried to add it using the java but didn't work so.... help me if you can!

posting the code I used right here.

```
ImageView header;
    header = findViewById(R.id.tour_image);

    if(String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("image")).equals(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_image))) {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("image")))
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(header);
    }else{
        Picasso.get()
                .load(String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("image")))
                .fit()
                .into(header);
    }

    header.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrim));
```

---

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tour_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `android:background` for sure will be covered with the content just because it is **back**ground. You need to add something in front of your ImageView. Put some view with transparent background in above ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add view with scrim in **CollapsingToolbarLayout**

```
     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

         <ImageView />

         <View 
             background="@drawable/scrim"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: This'll only work on API level 23 and above, I believe.